# Does = make_pair Invoke the Copy Constructor?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, temporary, std-pair

Normally the `=` in a variable declaration is treated by the compiler as move construction. For example:

```
vector<int> foo = vector<int>(13, 0);
```

Will call the `vector<int>::vector<int>(vector<int>&&)` constructor.

How does this work with `make_pair`? Am I constructing a temporary and moving it if I do:

```
pair<int, int> foo = make_pair(13, 0);
```

Obviously the consequence becomes more significant as the types in the `pair` are something heavier than `int`s, but the question remains the same. Is a temporary constructed here? If `make_pair` forces a temporary, I assume I could call:

```
pair<int, int> foo = pair(13, 0);
```

Either way, what about when the types can be implicitly converted, but are not identical? For example:

```
pair<string, int> foo = make_pair<"Hello World!", 13>;
```

Or:

```
pair<string, int> foo = pair("Hello World!", 13);
```

Is a temporary `pair<const char*, int>` created in this situation?

Comment: "Normal assignment operators" that isn't an assignment operator.

Comment: I would not say it is a duplicate. The question is in the title and not the same as the referenced duplicate.

Comment: @juanchopanza While Copy Elision is what I'm asking about, there isn't an answer there as to whether `make_pair` will be copy elided. Can you please reopen so I can get an answer pertaining to `make_pair`?

Comment: @Elyasin The duplicate answers the question.

Comment: @JonathanMee Funny, you seem to be asking about move construction and confusing initialization with assignment. Maybe you can clarify your question first.

Comment: I think one needs to be able to construct the bridges to understand that the duplicate answers the question(s). You're right though. However, I think here we might benefit from a concrete answer at an example from the STL, i.e. make_pair.

Comment: @juanchopanza I think you may be pointing out a misconception that I have. I've tried to clarify the question, but if it is a misconception, I might need you  to help straighten out my understanding before I can actually clarify the question.

Comment: First misconception is in my first comment. Second, you say an initialization expression involves a call to the move copy operator, but it doesn't if copy elision kicks in. You seem to be confusing assignment with initialization, and probably move semantics with copy elision.

Comment: @juanchopanza You say "That isn't an assignment operator", I know that it's normally elided, but I thought elision was up to the implementation, and it would be a legal implementation to compile this as two default constructors and an assignment operator. Is that not the case?

Comment: It not being an assignment operator has absolutely nothing to do with copies being elided or not. I think you are very confused. Assignment and initialization are different things in C++. And `T t = whatever;` is initialization, not assignment.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've edited to differentiate between assignment and initialization. Hopefully that meets your standard of excellence such that it can be reopened.

Comment: @juanchopanza I assumed when you said: "Maybe you can clarify your question first" you meant you were gonna reopen?

Comment: @JonathanMee No, I still think it is a duplicate. You're just too confused to see it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96708/discussion-between-jonathan-mee-and-juanchopanza).

Answer (score 0):

`std::make_pair` returns rvalue of pair object, then assignment operator `=` move the rvalue to lvalue, since std::pair have defined the [copy/move assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator%3D).

"Assignment to objects of a class is defined by the copy/move assignment operator."

Reference: Cpp11 Standard 5.17 Assignment and compound assignment operators.